# Str replace function

Tags: php, mysql

I want to censor words from a form string, and control the censor words with sql database. Here's what I have so far:

```
while ($bad_w = mysql_fetch_array($result_badw)) {
    $newmessage = str_replace($bad_w['word'],"****",$org);
}
```

Any ideas on how to correct it?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Just look at the code, it is obvious even without explanation.

Comment: @MightyPork addited..

Comment: Pointless exercise. Your filter can never match the creativity of people when it comes to bad words. Filters are [clbuttic](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2667634/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-When-obscenity-filters-go-wrong.html) sµck3rs! Implement a flagging system instead. On a side note, ext/mysql is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are repeatedly using the original string in your replacement. You should be overwriting the string
(`$org = str_replace($bad_w['word'],"****",$org)`) to ensure all words are filtered.

Just hope nobody talks about *Kuroshitsuji* on your forum :p

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite `$newmessage` each time you are replacing new word.

You should also use `str_ireplace()`, which is case-insensitive - that will be better for censorship.

**Try like this:**

```
$newmessage = $org;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_badw)) {
    $newmessage = str_ireplace($row['word'], "****", $newmessage);
}
```

---

Or, if you want the same number of `*` as are letters in the bad word:

```
$newmessage = $org;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_badw)) {
    $bword = $row['word'];
    $repl = str_repeat('*', strlen($bword));

    $newmessage = str_ireplace($bword, $repl, $newmessage);
}
```

Comment: edited it, make sure you use `str_ireplace`